# Triggering change event on file input when invoked from javascript (ie headache)

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, file-upload, onchange

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I've found fixes/hacks for this but none of them seem to be working.
Trying to use a single button/image (something) instead of the input-file control. It works so far except for in internet explorer. In ie the 'select file' dialog appears, lets you choose a file, the accompanying textbox gets populated but the change event doesn't fire.
I've tried focus, blur, live, onpropertychange, change, onchange... but they just won't work. Any help?

jQuery:

```
      $(function() {
            var a = $('a.#LinkUpload');
            var f = $('input.#file');
            a.click(function() {
                f.click();
            });
            f.change(function() {
                alert('changed!');
            });
        });
```

html:

```
    <body>
    <form action="">
        <div>
            <a id="LinkUpload">Click Me!</a>
            <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: That selector syntax, "input.#file", looks incorrect to me; it should be just "#file" since "id" values have to be unique anyway. It's actually slower to specify the tag name!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! (I think).

```
$(function() {
    var a = $('#LinkUpload');
    var f = $('#file');
    a.click(function() {
        f.click();
        setTimeout(function() {
            f.val(f.val());
        }, 1);
    });
    if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 9) {
        f.bind('propertychange', function() {
            alert('changed');
        });
    } else {
        f.change(function() {
            alert('changed!');
        });
    }
});
```

Seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

@Pointy said it.  If it's an ID, you don't need to specify the tag name, so just do something like:

```
var $a = $('#LinkUpload'),
    $b = $('#file');
```

It's also a good practice to add a $ (dollar sign) in your variable names when you're caching a jQuery object, just so you know that a variable is actually a jQuery object.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I'll code like you &/ Pointy demonstrated from now on

Comment: cool.  please accept the answer if you're happy with it.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly cleaner implementation of the file part of Oppdal's solution:

```
f.bind(($j.browser.msie && $j.browser.version < 9) ? 'propertychange' : 'change',
       function(){ 
           alert('changed!');
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

It has been changed in the new jQuery version. I updated from 1.4.4 to 1.6.2 and it works fine without the workaround.