# JQuery Form not submitting after uploading an image

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am making file upload control, I have a file upload control i have set its style display none and i have a button for uploading files

OnClicking the upload button i am opening fileupload' control Upload dialog, after after selecting file i have to submit the form but the form is not submitting even not any error msg is appearing,below is my code

```
<input type="file" id="newimg" style="display: none">
<input type="button" id="updnewimg">


  $('#updnewimg').live('click', function () {
            $('#newimg').click();
        });


 $('#newimg').change(function () {
            $("#ImgForm").submit();

        });
```

where ImgForm is my form's ID i've to use button here instead of submit

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5315528/triggering-change-event-on-file-input-when-invoked-from-javascript-ie-headache seems to suggest that older versions needed hacks to make the change event work.

Comment: I am using jquery-1.6.1.min.js

Comment: In my case,change event is firing properly but  form is not submitting ie $("#ImgForm").submit() is not working (no error is appearing)

Answer (score 0):

Can not understand why you are not doing something like this

```
<input type="file" id="newimg" style="display: none">
<input type="button" id="updnewimg">


  $('#updnewimg').live('click', function () {
           // any code about file upload
           $("#ImgForm").submit();
        });
```

**EDIT**
have you put the code inside a $(document).ready

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('#newimg').change(function () {
            $("#ImgForm").submit(function() {

              return false;
            });

        });
});
```

Comment: I am opening file upload dialog on clicking the updnewimg button,with this code i can submit the form but unable to open the file upload dialog

Comment: Is the above code placed inside  $(document).ready(function() {}); ?